# Typedef of structs

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am using structs in my project in this way:

```
typedef struct
{
    int str1_val1;
    int str1_val2;
} struct1;
```

and

```
typedef struct
{
    int str2_val1;
    int str2_val2;
    struct1* str2_val3;
} struct2;
```

Is it possible that I hack this definition in a way, that I would use only types with my code, like

```
struct2* a;
a = (struct2*) malloc(sizeof(struct2));
```

without using keyword `struct`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, could you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish? And I would write that last line as `a = malloc(sizeof *a);`

Comment: I fixed that, I am using typechange becuse on my system there is primitive function called calloc1 (yes that is right) and it returns char*, but that does not matter

Comment: Then you should wrap this perverse `calloc1` function with a function that returns `void *` (or just use a macro to do this).

Comment: Never typecast the value returned by `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc`.  It's less readable, and the only way it'll make a difference is if you forgot `#include <stdlib.h>`, in which case you'll want to know you forgot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as follows:

```
struct _struct1
{
...
};
typedef struct _struct1 struct1;

struct _struct2
{
...
};
typedef struct _struct2 struct2;

...

struct2 *a;
a = (struct2*)malloc(sizeof(struct2));
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem in the other file, then. Because this code looks correct.

Comment: I knew I got it, problem was in other h file declared just before this one same "wrong way"

Comment: Get rid of the underscores in the struct tags. They're unnecessary and if misused can lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the typedef'ed symbol without needing the struct keyword. The compiler simply uses that name as an alias for the structure you defined earlier.

One note on your example, malloc returns a pointer to memory. Hence your statement should read

```
a = (struct2 *)malloc(sizeof(struct2));
```

Comment: @ralu:  So what is the point?  This looks like the answer to the question you asked; what did you mean to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Just to share, I've seen this approach, and though I personally don't like it (I like everything named and tagged =P and I don't like using variable names in malloc), someone may.

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} *some_t;

int main() {
    some_t var = (some_t) malloc(sizeof(*var));
}
```

Comment: <xxxx>_t names are reserved for the implemenation

Answer (score 0):

as a footnote. If you code in C++ then you don't need to do the typedef; a struct is a type automatically.